# Ng-show swaping DOM opacity animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, typescript

i got a little problem doing animation on ngShow.

I got 2 DOM elements, one is visibly until the var changes and swap with the other.

```
<card-view ng-show="enemy[3] !== null" name="enemy[3].Name" img="enemy[3].ImageUrl" atk="enemy[3].Atk" def="enemy[3].Def" life="enemy[3].Life"
                       cat="enemy[3].Category" tier="enemy[3].Tier" elem="enemy[3].ElementId.ElementId" desc="" ng-click="performAttack(3)"></card-view>
            <div class="battle-no-card" ng-show="enemy[3] === null"></div>
```

The problem is: while the animation is performing, the second element appears on the right before the first one dissapears.

How i can to avoid the second element appears before the first one is completely faded.

Thank you :)

UPDATE:

Nevermind. I got the answer. Just encapsulate the two element in a div, making both absolute position, so one overlap another and i can create the animation.

Update: closed

Answer (score 0):

So ng-show can take a function that returns true or false to trigger.

Just have the show function you want to render first call the show function in the item you want to render second and you should have the effect you're looking for.